# scikit-learn PCA transform returns incorrect reduced feature length

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I try to apply PCA in my code and when I train my data using the following code:

```
def gather_train():
    train_data = np.array([])
    train_labels = np.array([])
    with open(training_info, "r") as traincsv:
        for line in traincsv:
            current_image = "train\\{}".format(line.strip().split(",")[0])
            print "Reading data from: {}".format(current_image)
            train_labels = np.append(train_labels, int(line.strip().split(",")[1]))
            with open(current_image, "rb") as img:
                train_data = np.append(train_data, np.fromfile(img, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(-1, 784)/255.0)
    train_data = train_data.reshape(len(train_labels), 784)
    return train_data, train_labels

def get_PCA_train(data):
    print "\nFitting PCA. Components: {} ...".format(PCA_components)
    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=PCA_components).fit(data)
    print "\nReducing data to {} components ...".format(PCA_components)
    data_reduced = pca.fit_transform(data)
    return data_reduced

def get_PCA_test(data):
    print "\nFitting PCA. Components: {} ...".format(PCA_components)
    pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=PCA_components).fit(data)
    print "\nReducing data to {} components ...".format(PCA_components)
    data_reduced = pca.transform(data)
    return data_reduced

def gather_test(imgfile):
    #input is a file, and reads data from it. different from gather_train which gathers all at once
    with open(imgfile, "rb") as img:
        return np.fromfile(img, dtype=np.uint8,).reshape(-1, 784)/255.0

...

train_data = gather_train()
train_data_reduced = get_PCA_train(train_data)
print train_data.ndim, train_data.shape
print train_data_reduced.ndim, train_data_reduced.shape
```

It prints the ff, which is expected:

```
2 (1000L, 784L)
2 (1000L, 300L)
```

But when I begin to reduce my test data:

```
test_data = gather_test(image_file)
# image_file is 784 bytes (28x28) of pixel values; 1 byte = 1 pixel value
test_data_reduced = get_PCA_test(test_data)
print test_data.ndim, test_data.shape
print test_data_reduced.ndim, test_data_reduced.shape
```

The output is:

```
2 (1L, 784L)
2 (1L, 1L)
```

which results in the error later on:

> ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 300, the number of
>   features at training time

Why is test_data_reduced of shape `(1,1)`, not `(1,300)`? I have tried using `fit_transform` for training data and `transform` for testing data only but still the same error.

Comment: What does your data look like, can you post some mockups?  You're applying the PCA wrong though, you should be fit_transform on the training data, and then just transforming the test data.  When you re-fit on the test data you essentially are ignoring your training data.  Also, you should post more complete code - how are you defining train_data and test_data?

Comment: What @flyingmeatball is correct, it's because you're retraining you PCA model on the test data.

Comment: @flyingmeatball I have added more code. The flow here is that `train_data` is similar with `test_data` only that `test_data` is single entry

Comment: I used `fit_transform` on `train_data` and `transform` on `test_data` but I still get the same error

Comment: But two lines above the `transform` you still `fit` the `test` data. You need to use the `training` data.

Comment: @sietschie ooh I understand now. Thanks for that. I really was implementing PCA wrongly. I rectified my mistake by using the `pca` object from training and inputting into it the `test_data` from `transform`

Comment: Happy to help. I transformed the comment into an answer so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `PCA` has to look roughly like this:

```
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=PCA_components).fit(train_data)
data_reduced = pca.transform(test_data)
```

First you call `fit` on the training data and then `transform` on the testing data, you want to reduce.